# Gitlab reconfigure error

Tags: gitlab

I am installing gitlab on ubuntu 14.04 according to the download section, but stuck on the last command, the reconfigure failed with the following log, I noticed 2 instances of errors but have no idea what to do about it.. it is unicorn and sidekiq that throws the error.. Any idea will be appreciated..

```
    Recipe: gitlab::gitlab-rails
  * execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache] action run

================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received ''
---- Begin output of /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake cache:clear ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
---- End output of /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake cache:clear ----
Ran /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake cache:clear returned 

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/gitlab-rails.rb

325: execute "clear the gitlab-rails cache" do
326:   command "/opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake cache:clear"
327:   action :nothing
328: end
329: 

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/gitlab-rails.rb:325:in `from_file'

execute("clear the gitlab-rails cache") do
  action [:nothing]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :execute
  command "/opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake cache:clear"
  backup 5
  returns 0
  declared_type :execute
  cookbook_name "gitlab"
  recipe_name "gitlab-rails"
end

Recipe: gitlab::unicorn
```

* service[unicorn] action restart
    - restart service service[unicorn]
    Recipe: gitlab::sidekiq
  * service[sidekiq] action restart

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `restart` on resource 'service[sidekiq]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chpst -u root /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv restart /opt/gitlab/service/sidekiq ----
STDOUT: timeout: run: /opt/gitlab/service/sidekiq: (pid 27304) 963s, got TERM
STDERR: 
---- End output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chpst -u root /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv restart /opt/gitlab/service/sidekiq ----
Ran /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chpst -u root /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv restart /opt/gitlab/service/sidekiq returned 1

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/runit/definitions/runit_service.rb

191:     service params[:name] do
192:       control_cmd = node[:runit][:sv_bin]
193:       if params[:owner]
194:         control_cmd = "#{node[:runit][:chpst_bin]} -u #{params[:owner]} #{control_cmd}"
195:       end
196:       provider Chef::Provider::Service::Simple

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/runit/definitions/runit_service.rb:191:in `block in from_file'

service("sidekiq") do
  params {:directory=>"/opt/gitlab/sv", :only_if=>false, :finish_script=>false, :control=>[], :run_restart=>true, :active_directory=>"/opt/gitlab/service", :init_script_template=>nil, :owner=>"root", :group=>"root", :template_name=>"sidekiq", :start_command=>"start", :stop_command=>"stop", :restart_command=>"restart", :status_command=>"status", :options=>{:rails_app=>"gitlab-rails", :user=>"git", :shutdown_timeout=>4, :concurrency=>25, :log_directory=>"/var/log/gitlab/sidekiq", :directory=>nil, :only_if=>false, :finish_script=>false, :control=>[], :run_restart=>true, :active_directory=>nil, :init_script_template=>nil, :owner=>"root", :group=>"root", :template_name=>"sidekiq", :start_command=>"start", :stop_command=>"stop", :restart_command=>"restart", :status_command=>"status", :options=>{}, :log_options=>{}, :env=>{}, :action=>:enable, :down=>false}, :log_options=>{"svlogd_size"=>209715200, "svlogd_num"=>30, "svlogd_timeout"=>86400, "svlogd_filter"=>"gzip", "svlogd_udp"=>nil, "svlogd_prefix"=>nil, "udp_log_shipping_host"=>nil, "udp_log_shipping_port"=>514, "logrotate_frequency"=>"daily", "logrotate_size"=>nil, "logrotate_rotate"=>30, "logrotate_compress"=>"compress", "logrotate_method"=>"copytruncate", "logrotate_postrotate"=>nil, "logrotate_dateformat"=>nil, "enable"=>true, "ha"=>false, "log_directory"=>"/var/log/gitlab/sidekiq", "shutdown_timeout"=>4, "concurrency"=>25}, :env=>{}, :action=>:enable, :down=>false, :name=>"sidekiq"}
  provider Chef::Provider::Service::Simple
  action [:nothing]
  supports {:restart=>true, :status=>true}
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  service_name "sidekiq"
  pattern "sidekiq"
  start_command "/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chpst -u root /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv start /opt/gitlab/service/sidekiq"
  stop_command "/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chpst -u root /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv stop /opt/gitlab/service/sidekiq"
  status_command "/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chpst -u root /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv status /opt/gitlab/service/sidekiq"
  restart_command "/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/chpst -u root /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/sv restart /opt/gitlab/service/sidekiq"
  declared_type :service
  cookbook_name "gitlab"
  recipe_name "sidekiq"
end


Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 7 resources updated in 59 minutes 30 seconds
```

Comment: looks not good. Are all services online of gitlab? You can only reconfigure if all services especially the DB is on. You can check the status of all gitlab services by executing `gitlab-rake gitlab:check`

Comment: sudo gitlab-rake cache:clear