# Docker completely remove container and image

Tags: docker, gitlab

Reinstalling gitlab docker issue

So today I messed up accidentally typed docker-compose down instead of stop and since my dockerfile has "latest" tag it tried to update it and it failed now I can't access it.

From my understanding ce version is being discontinued and ee is recommended so I don't mind reinstalling and even loosing my data since there were only two repos anyway but whenever I try to install gitlab-ee:latest I get this error
"It seems you are upgrading from major version 12 to major version 15...."

I did ran `docker volume prune` and `docker system prune -a,` but I still get same error. How can I completely delete old ce gitlab and install latest ee version?

Also I'm using laradock so I just replace `FROM gitlab-ce:latest` to `FROM gitlab-ee:latest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it might be laradock specific but if anyone encounters something similair I did this:

**Keep in mind that this will delete all non running images and volumes so make sure that containers you want to leave is running**

```
docker volume prune

docker system prune
```

And then (in my case) /home/[your_user]/.laradock/data delete everything gitlab related.

It did actually complained when I tried to pull gitlab-ce but did all steps again and gitlab-ee installed without issues.

Answer (score 1):

> From my understanding ce version is being discontinued and ee is recommended

Not that I know of. [`gitlab-ce` Docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/tags) is very much maintained.

And you could reinstall the [`12.10.14-ce.0`](https://registry.hub.docker.com/layers/gitlab-ce/gitlab/gitlab-ce/12.10.14-ce.0/images/sha256-918b5377bc06d3ed5215a00071d46e5030a68459250803fba5ae4013aa77d102?context=explore), which would still be compatible with your old version.

By using a `FROM gitlab/gitlab-ce:12.10.14-ce.0` instead of `gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest` means that a `docker-compose` would not accidentally upgrade your GitLab.

Comment: Ok I misread it's still maintained but when I set certain tag I still get other errors. Using your version I get "Error executing action `restart` on resource 'runit_service[mailroom]'" and lots of other. As I said I don't mind completely wiping it out and reinstalling but volume and system prune isn't enough. What else should I delete?

Comment: @Trekstler Check if https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/321841#note_513813306 could help.

Comment: @Trekstler Also, [clearing the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36790965/gitlab-reconfigure-error#comment67473087_36790965)

Comment: That didn't really solved my issue but +1 for trying to help, thanks